# Visual Studio editing my Form1.Designer.cs without no sense

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, telerik

I have a very complicated project on visual studio 150mb for 15.000 lines of code but after my last windows resinstallation, i open my project and after editing a visual element visual studio delete code from Form1.Designer.cs.

Program without editing:

[image]

Program after visual editing ex: adding a labeltext:

[image]

I need reset every time with my personal svn the Form1.Designer.cs:

Left old version working on svn, right auto-editing of visual studio, it delete 3/4 of my code, why???!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but I see that in designer disappears telerik references.
Have you installed all telerik dependencies after windows reinstallation?

Comment: yes im not that stupid! I have $1,200 of license for telerik and devexpress, installed at the same version of project!

Comment: ... and the very same version?

Comment: VS delete telerik and other element, not only telerik!

Comment: And it was a reinstall on the same machine? Some tools have problems with 4K support for example.

Comment: The working project is compilated with 1920x1080 the new project on new pc is 4k.. =(

Comment: So it wasn't a reinstall at all. It was a new system... Check if Telerik has support for 4K. Even though, winforms has issues with the designer on 4K. I have a 4K screen too.

Comment: Same pc, same windows 10 pro x64, i have changed processor from 6800k to 6900k and new monitor from 1080p on 4k.. Now i try in virtual machine with 1080p.. thanks for the info of resolution

Comment: Something is just wrong and it could be anything based on those screenshots: properties are deleted, not controls; locations are changed, etc. What I recommend doing is copy the old code and paste it back into the designer. When you look at the designer again, does it work or does it get deleted again? Ignore any get out of source control for now and try to get it working manually so you can check it back in.

Comment: I paste the old designer but the modification of visual are cancelled, i write the new code for function in normal cs and its possibile to compile, now i need to change the gui =(

Comment: Problem fixed @PatrickHofman thank you, create a answer i make winner! Create a VM with 1080p and all work perfectly! Telerik not work on 4K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have often seen problems with the Visual Studio Windows Forms designer running on a 4K screen. Apparently you have the same issues now too.

As you indicated, switching back to a 2K screen will fix the issue. You might want to check out with Telerik if this is a known issue or if there is any support at all for the 4K designer.

Comment: For me with 2K and 4K i have same problem only with 1080p the problem is solved =)

Comment: 1080p = 1920x1080 = 2K

Comment: Ehm, 1080p is 1920x1080, 2K = 2048 × 1080, 2.5K 2560x1440 and 4K 3840 × 2160 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2K_resolution 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution